# Mutex error with batch file and group policy

Tags: batch-file

I have a very simple batch file attached to a group policy that is supposed to install an *.msi*. For some reason, when I apply the GP to the OU I want and restart said computers, the program will only install on some (not all) of the computers in the OU. The MSI in question is located on a network share that is accessible by all computers. I created a log export for the GP, compared it to the installs that work and I noticed two things:

1) `Failed to grab execution mutex. System error 258`

2) `MainEngineThread is returning 1618`

It looks like the 1618 is due to an application already running. How can I fix my batch file to resolve this issue? I'm just starting to work with batch files and any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is what the batch looks like currently:

```
:: Test if Websense is already installed
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Websense\Websense Endpoint\WEPDiag.exe" GOTO _end
:_skipcheck

msiexec /package "\\\networkshare\Websense Endpoint.msi" /passive /L*V C:\Windows\Temp\websenseinstall.log WSCONTEXT=ouruniquewebsensecode
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens simply because the file is already in use by another computer meaning that the installer can't be opened on that problematic PC(s). To fix this simply set the file 'Websense Endpoint.msi' to Read-Only, then no computer can get a lock on a file.

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively here is a batch file that will attempt 100 times to launch the MSI:

This script will:

**1.** Attempt to copy the file to a temporary folder (100 times)
 **2.** Launch the MSI from the temporary folder
 **3.** Show an appropriate message when finished

```
@echo off
:: Change the below variables according to your preference
set maximumTries=100
set MsiFile=\\\networkshare\Websense Endpoint.msi
set TempMsiFile=%temp%\Websense Endpoint.msi
:: Don't change any of the below

set tries=0
:TryAgain
if "%tries%" == "%maximumTries%" goto :NoFile
if not exist "%msifile%" set /a tries=%tries%+1>nul&goto :TryAgain
set tries=0
:CopyToTemp
if "%Tries%" == "%maximumTries%" goto :NoGoCopy
copy /Y %MsiFile% "%TempMsiFile%" >nul 2>&1
if not "%errorlevel%" == "0"  set /a tries=%tries%+1>nul&goto CopyToTemp
msiexec /package "%TempMsiFile%" /passive /L*V C:\Windows\Temp\websenseinstall.log WSCONTEXT=ouruniquewebsensecode
goto :EndYes
:NoGoCopy
echo Cannot Read The File Specified! (Attempted %tries% Times)
goto :end
:NoFile
echo Cannot Find The File Specified!
goto :end
:endYes
echo The command completed successfully!
pause
exit
:end
echo The command failed!
pause
exit
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: Ok (Make sure that the file is not open on any PC when you set it to read-only)

Comment: Well, it still doesn't want to install on all machines consistently, but it looks like I'm no longer getting the mutex error or the 1618 error. It's showing a 1619 error, which looks like it's unable to open the .msi. After rebooting that computer individually, (I typically have been rebooting ~20 at a time) it installs the msi just fine. While I could do this, I have a ton of computers to hit and it's just not practical. Have any thoughts on this?